# Read txt file as a numeric array in R

Tags: r, csv, sorting

I am using RStudio in a MAC (10.14.6), and I am trying to read a text file that looks like this

```
5:[0.12126984126984124, 0.11682539682539679, 0.14666666666666664, 0.07269841269841269, 0.06984126984126983, 0.0911111111111111, 0.1092063492063492, 0.12253968253968253, 0.08698412698412696, 0.09523809523809523, 0.12222222222222222, 0.10761904761904759]
```

I've used several iterations of "read", "read.delim", and "read.csv" and all pretty much do the same

```
> data.matrix(read.delim("data.txt",sep=','))

     X5..0.12126984126984124 X0.11682539682539679 X0.14666666666666664 X0.07269841269841269 X0.06984126984126983
     X0.0911111111111111 X0.1092063492063492 X0.12253968253968253 X0.08698412698412696 X0.09523809523809523
     X0.12222222222222222 X0.10761904761904759.
```

Using "unlist", "as.numeric", "as.character" does not yield anything most likely due to the presence of the X in front of each number. Does anyone have ideas to read this file properly?

Comment: Try https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_number.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are only interested in reading the numbers, then you first have to delete `5:[` at the beginning and also `]` at the end. then read using `scan` with the `sep = ','`

```
scan(text=gsub("^.*\\[|\\]", "", string), sep = ",")
Read 12 items
 [1] 0.12126984 0.11682540 0.14666667 0.07269841 0.06984127 0.09111111
 [7] 0.10920635 0.12253968 0.08698413 0.09523810 0.12222222 0.10761905
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I ended up using ```as.numeric(scan("data.txt",sep=","))```